# Fitnesse java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/validator/ValidatorException

Tags: java, maven, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I am trying to test java methods within a multiple package project that has numerous imports. It works fine until it gets to the javax imports. Tnen it complains that it cannot find the class definition for this import. Do I need to explicitly import a jar even though it was part of the maven dependencies when I complied the jars that this project is using?

This is the declarations section of my code package

```
package com.fietrade.swtf.swreconcilation.beans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandler;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.fietrade.swtf.persistance.factories.DBMgrFactory;
import com.fietrade.swtf.persistance.factories.ReconciliationDBMgr;
import com.fietrade.swtf.persistance.swapswire.Reconciliation;


public class ReconciliationEditor {
```

And this is the error:

```
__EXCEPTION__:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/validator/ValidatorException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.getClass(SlimExecutionContext.java:139) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.searchPathsForClass(SlimExecutionContext.java:129) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.createInstanceOfConstructor(SlimExecutionContext.java:100) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimExecutionContext.create(SlimExecutionContext.java:42) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:75) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.MakeInstruction.executeInternal(MakeInstruction.java:26) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.Instruction.execute(Instruction.java:30) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatement(ListExecutor.java:50) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatements(ListExecutor.java:44) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor.execute(ListExecutor.java:84) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.executeInstructions(SlimServer.java:106) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processTheInstructions(SlimServer.java:93) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processOneSetOfInstructions(SlimServer.java:68) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.tryProcessInstructions(SlimServer.java:54) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.serve(SlimServer.java:40) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.handle(SlimService.java:164) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.acceptOne(SlimService.java:172) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.accept(SlimService.java:134) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.startWithFactory(SlimService.java:65) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.main(SlimService.java:51) [fitnesse-standalone-20140903.jar]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException
```

Can someone explain what this error is and how to resolve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically it says It is not able to find a dependancy for your project to work ..

include [jsf-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this to your project and error will be resolved.